# Potentially locking the event loop in Node.js through EventEmitter

Tags: events, node.js, asynchronous, blocking, eventemitter

Suppose the following scenario:

```
//Where "e" is a global object in the app  
e = new EventEmitter;  

...  

//at some place in the app code I'm adding Listener 1
e.on('myEvent', function() {console.log('Listener 1)});  

...  

//at another place in the app code I'm adding Listener 2
e.on('myEvent', function() {console.log('Listener 2)});  

...  

//at another place in the app code I'm adding Listener N
e.on('myEvent', function() {console.log('Listener N)});  

...  

//finally in some place I'm emitting "myEvent"
e.emit('myEvent', p1, p2);
```

At the moment that "e.emit('myEvent', p1, p2)" is being executed, it is my code who is with the control of the Node main thread (not the event loop). And the "emit" function is a synchronous one, so "emit" is calling at this very moment each of the Listeners attached to "myEvent" (in the above example N listeners). Thus, in fact, calling "e.emit('myEvent', p1, p2)" is equivalent to make the following calls in the traditional imperative paradigm:

```
Listener1(p1,p2);
Listener2(p1,p2); 
... 
ListenerN(p1,p2);
```

And if N is big, I'm blocking the event loop, cause its my current code who is in control of the main thread, not the event loop.

This scenario is true and possible? Is for this reason that by default Node.js has a maximum of 10 listeners?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since Javascript (without manually creating child processes) is single-threaded, everything you perform in code means that it's executed sequentially. The language itself is synchronous. In the case you use EventEmitter to add listeners, it still executes everything one after another as you added them. It's possible to choke Node with a bunch of manual event emitting, but it's the same as to have a `while(true)` loop, which will have a similar result. EventEmitter is there, just to have the possibility of using the same pattern as built-in modules. A rough equivalent to EventEmitter would be the following:

```
var handlers = [];

function addHandler(fn) {
  handlers.push(fn);
}

function emit() {
  for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
    handlers[i]();
  }
}

// Add a bunch of handlers
addHandler(function(){console.log('foobar 1');});
....
addHandler(function(){console.log('foobar N');});

// Fire the event
emit();
```

The asynchronous part is the combination of OS and Node, which enables you to delegate tasks such as file reading, buffering etc to the OS itself, which basically does it in another thread, leaving Node free to run the event loop. When the OS fires an event to Node that the file read is complete, it then performs necessary modifications you wrote inside your JS. While running the handler of the completed file read, the whole event loop is still stopped, as there is a single instance of JS execution at any time.

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html#emitter.setMaxListeners):

> By default EventEmitters will print a warning if more than 10
>   listeners are added to it.    This is a useful default which helps
>   finding memory leaks. Obviously not all Emitters should be limited to
>   10.

Hope it cleared at least something.